# Continuity of function $f(x)$ at irrational numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $\{q_k:\ k \in \mathbb N^+\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,\ 1)$ and let $(a_k)$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 1
$$

Denote $S(x) = \{k \in \mathbb N^+:\ q_k \in [0,\ x)\}$ i.e. indices of rational numbers in $[0,\ x)$ and define $f:[0,\ 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sum_{k \in S(x)} a_k & (x > 0) \\
0 & (x = 0)
\end{cases}
$$

I know that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at every positive rational number. I speculate that $f(x)$ is continuous at irrational numbers, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an answer in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008548/increasing-function-on-r-that-is-discontinuous-on-the-rationals/3008948#3008948). Although the situation is more special, because there $a_k = 2^{-k}$ is chosen, the proof doesn't change. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be irrational, and let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\sum_{k=N1}^\infty a_n < \varepsilon/2$. Now define
$$\delta:= \min_{i=1,\ldots,N}|q_i-x|.$$
For any $|y-x| < \delta$ we have $q_k \in [0,x)$ if and only if $q_k \in [0,y)$ for all $k=1,\ldots,N$. Thus $$S(x) \cap [1,N] = S(y) \cap [1,N]$$
and therefore
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le 2 \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_k<\varepsilon.$$