# Does there any diffentiable function $f$ such that $f'$ is discontinuous exactly on $\Bbb{Q} $ and continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, elementary-set-theory

Does there exists
any diffentiable function $f$ such that $f'$ is discontinuous exactly on $\Bbb{Q} $ and continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$ ?

---

Since $\Bbb{Q}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ , we can produce a function which is discontinuous only on $\Bbb{Q}$.

For an example we can pick [Thomae's function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).But Thomae's function has no primitive. Because if thomae's function $f$ has a primitive $F$ then $F'=f $ . Since $F'$ is Darboux function, image of $F'=f$ must contains an intervals and this is not possible as Thomae's function doesn't attain irrational values.

By choosing a particular example, we can conclude the impossibility of existence of such function.

---

If $f'$ is Darboux function and belongs to Baire class $1$ then $f'$ has a primitive $f$ .

Hence our goal is to create a Darboux function $f'$ of Baire class $1$ which is continuous on $\Bbb{Q}$ and discontinuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$.

How to produce such function?

Comment: Dave Renfro's comprehensive answer to [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be) is probably of interest.

Comment: Just saw this question now. Near the beginning of the answer @Andrew D. Hwang cites is: *More precisely, a subset* $D$ *of* $\mathbb R$ *can be the discontinuity set for some derivative if and only if* $D$ *is an* $F_{\sigma}$ *first category (i.e. an* $F_{\sigma}$ *meager) subset of* $\mathbb R.$ The rationals are such a set -- $F_{\sigma}$ because a countable union of singleton sets each of which is a closed set; first category because a countable union of singleton sets each of which is a nowhere dense set -- so the answer is YES. Maybe for an answer someone can give an explicit example.

Comment: *Since* $\Bbb{Q}$ *is* $G_{\delta}$ , *we can produce a function which is discontinuous only on* $\Bbb{Q}$. --- This is not correctly worded, and probably should be revised to one of the following two versions: "Since $\Bbb{Q}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ , we can produce a function which is discontinuous only on $\Bbb{Q}$." OR "Since $\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$ is $G_{\delta}$ , we can produce a function which is continuous only on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$."

Comment: Sorry $\Bbb{Q}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set. I have made a mistake there. I will fix immediately.

Comment: @LostinSpace My intuitive idea: What if we take $f$ from [this answer on StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3008948/998803) (noting that $f$ is increasing, continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and discontinuous on $\mathbb{Q}$) and define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(y)dy$? I think this fulfills your requirements.

Comment: @Andreas: That does not work because $f$ has jump discontinuities at the rational numbers, so it can not be the derivative of some function $F$ (it does not have the intermediate value property).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following result is quoted in [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be/112133#112133), with references to several proofs:

> A subset $D$ of $\mathbb R$ can be the discontinuity set for some derivative if and only if $D$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ first category (i.e. an $F_{\sigma}$ meager) subset of $\mathbb R.$

One of the references which is also online available is

- Bruckner, A. M., and J. L. Leonard. “Derivatives.” The American Mathematical Monthly 73, no. 4 (1966): 24–56. https://doi.org/10.2307/2313749.

$\Bbb Q$ surely is an $F_{\sigma}$ first category set, so there does exist a differentiable function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ such that $f'$ is discontinuous exactly on $\Bbb Q$. Inspecting the proof from the Bruckner/Leonard article, one can construct such a function for this set:

Let $h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function with the following properties:

- $h$ is differentiable everywhere.
- $h'$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.
- $h$ and $h'$ are bounded.

(For example, $h(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne 0$, $h(0) = 0$.)

Now let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers, and define $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} h(x-q_n) \, .
$$

Both $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} h(x-q_n) $ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} h'(x-q_n) $ converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$, so that $f$ is differentiable with
$$
 f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} h'(x-q_n) \, .
$$

$f'$ is continuous at every irrational point $x_0$ because all functions $3^{-n} h'(x-q_n)$ are continuous at $x_0$ and the series for $f'$ converges uniformly.

And $f'$ is discontinuous at every $q_m \in \Bbb Q$ because in
$$
 f'(x) = 3^{-m} h'(x-q_m) + \sum_{n \ne m} 3^{-n} h'(x-q_n) \, .
$$
the first term on the right is discontinuous at $q_m$, whereas the second term is continuous at $q_m$, again as a uniformly convergent series of functions which are all continuous at $q_m$.

Comment: Very interesting....

Comment: @Lost in Space: For those interested, [here](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/andy1966.pdf) is a freely available copy of the Bruckner/Leonard paper.